# select statement in m:n relationship

Tags: t-sql, select, many-to-many

i have three tables:

USER
userid
fname
lname

GROUP
groupid
description

USER_GROUP
usergroupid
userid
groupid

i need to get the first and last name of the users table. what is given is the group description. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.Fname,
        a.LName,
        c.Description
FROM    [USER] a
        INNER JOIN [USER_GROUP] b
            ON a.userID = b.userID
        INNER JOIN [GROUP] c
            ON b.groupid = c.groupID
WHERE   c.Description = 'description_here'
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT USER.*
FROM USER 
  INNER JOIN USER_GROUP ON USER.userid = USER_GROUP.userid
  INNER JOIN [GROUP] ON USER_[GROUP].groupid = [GROUP].groupid
WHERE [GROUP].description = 'Blah blah'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
   Select FName, LName
   From user u
   Where Exists 
       (Select * From user_Group ug
            join group g On g.GroupId = ug.groupId
        Where ug.userId = u.UserId
            anf g.description = @GroupDescription)
```

Comment: ok i have tested this and it seems to work, now my only problem is, perhaps i should have also mentioned this, how to pass the @GroupDescription variable from another gridview? i am using 2 gridviews, one for displaying the groups and one for displaying the members of a group. the gridview for displaying groups has two columns: description and a buttonfield. when the user clicks the button in this field, a new gridview is displayed with the members of the group...